# Intersecting with LINQ on single column

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 queries.

```
var suppliers = 
    from u in db.Users
    join s in db.Suppliers
    on u.SupplierID equals s.supplierID
    select u;

var AreaServiced = 
    from a in db.Areas_Serviceds
    where a.Area.AreaName == AreasServiced
    where a.Area.State == StateServiced
    select a;
```

and I want to to intersect them to get all the supplier details. So they would just be intersecting on supplierID.

I cant use suppliers = suppliers.intersect(AreaServiced)

because suppliers and areasserviced do not have the same columns.

I currently dont have it in a single statemnet because I dont ALWAYS want htem to intersect (if the user doesnt care about area serviced then i will jsut display the suppleirs without caring where they service)

so later on i can do something like If (!customerCaresAboutAreaServiced) { intersect two tables }

otherwsie i would ignore second table.

Comment: Can't you just do a join on SupplierId?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a Linq join between the two queries?
Something like

```
var intersection = 
    from su in suppliers
    join areas in AreaServiced 
    on su.SupplierID equals areas.SupplierID
```